# Suddenly lost reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

Before few minutes I was having Reputation 169 ( on Stack Overflow ), which I got by Edit Approval. Now it is showing me 165.

What could be the reason behind this ?

Comment: Maybe some post you got reputation from, like editing, got deleted or similar?

Comment: you mean, if the question gets deleted which i edited, so my reputation get decrement for same ?

Comment: Indeed. If you go to the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/users/1289473/krish?tab=reputation&sort=post and check "show removed posts" can you see any such loss of rep?

Comment: Yes, I have already "ticked" that option, but it is not showing anything deleted

Comment: ok got it, actually they were yesterday's edited questions, which are now deleted. Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any questions or answers, it may be that you picked up a couple down-votes. If not, something else you picked up positive reputation from probably got deleted.

In any event, the system isn't broken. In time if you continue to make quality contributions, your rep will go up even if you see small setbacks from deletions etc. Don't sweat it. Analyze it and see if you can learn anything, even if that is what is so low quality that it isn't worth salvaging, then move on to positive contributions.

Comment: ok, well first I checked my reputation in my profile, and there was no down vote, the only thing is that, i didnt knew about this delete Questions term.